# How to recover data from faulty NAS (2 HDD in RAID 1)

Tags: raid-1, recovery

my NAS drive (2 HDD in RAID 1) stopped working and I need to recover the data.
I assume that 1 out of 2 HDD drives from the NAS has failed and the data can be recovered using the other working drive, but not sure how can it be done. Can anyone advise how to do this please?

The NAS is a Buffalo Linkstation LS220D0D0402-EU, with 2x 2TB WD Blue HDDs
When I connect both HDD to a PC (with SATA to USB adapter) it's says that drive is not accessible and it's asking to format it.

Comment: You have not provided anything like the amount of detail required to help you.  You may want to edit your post to include that ngs like the make and model of NAS and how the failure manifests.

Comment: As a general rule for RAID1 - you can take the disks out of the NAS and read the data off them individually - ie as if there were no RAID.  I am not sure this is globally correct but has been the case on all hardware I've tested it on.

Comment: Ita worth noting that RAID1 should NOT  fail if a drive fails - rather a nofification shoud be sent to replace the failed disk.  If thr NAS is not working ot is likely there are either problems with both disks or there is a hardware failure seperate from the disks.

Comment: Thank you Davidgo, I updated the post with the details you asked for

Comment: One important bit of info missing is where/how do you see the drive failure on the NAS (not connecting it to a PC, as the PC doesn't know about the RAID, but on the NAS itself that knows about the RAID and should be able to indicate what's going on.)

Comment: What OS you attach the drives to? If Windows, it won't know what do with partition types / file systems it can not handle. Which is very likely to be the case as most (all?) NAS boxes run a flavor of Linux and use Ext, XFS etc..

Comment: So the two drives don't come from the same enclosure? How is it a RAID then?

Comment: I have 2 Linkstation 220D NAS enclosures. Both 2TB HDDs came with original enclosures and where configured in RAID 1
The old one without inserted drives it gives error code "The firmware is corrupted"
With connected drives it gives error code “Updating the LinkStation firmware” (and stays like this for hours)
In both cases NAS Navigator tool doesn’t find it on the network

Comment: Both HDDs  I tried to connect to PC running Windows 11. When I connect either HDD it shows 4-5 new partitions but none of them can be opened. There is an error message saying that drive is not accessible

Comment: Firstly, I think you should at least keep an open mind on the possibility of getting the NAS enclosures to work. You mentioned the old enclosure that is stuck in firmware upgrade, what's the status when you boot the new one with the drives connected? As for recovering the data by connecting to the Windows PC, what info does Disk Management show for the 4-5 partitions?

Comment: Brand new NAS (the same model) without HDDs inserted shows no errors. 
With both HDDs inside it shows the same error code as the old NAS - “Updating the LinkStation firmware” (and stays like this for hours)
When I connect the HDD to PC; in Windows Computer Management it shows the following
D – 977MB (RAW)
E – 4.77GB (RAW)
G – 977MB (RAW)
H – 1842.52GB (RAW)
All partitions RAW, Healthy (Basic Data Partition)

Answer (score 2):

There is a paucity of meaningful information on useful details about this device but it seems that -

- from your description of the problem the disks are physically Ok.
- Its extremely likely the issue of reading the data off the disks in Windows is that it does not understand the filesystem used.
- The filesystem is probably XFS - which is supported on Unix.  This is not an extremely common filesystem but was probably on the rise when the system was developed and can be accessed.

There are (at least) 2 ways to tackle this -

- The way I would do it is to attach a drive to a Linux system, mount it and pull the data off.  This is definately the superior way - but requires Linux skills.  If you don't have Linux skills maybe find a LUG (Linux User Group) or a student doing computer science at a Uni/Trade School to help.
- Find some data recovery software that can work under Windows.  Google came up with UFS Explorer. Never used it - not a recommendation. Paragon Software claim read-only support for XFS under Windows.  I've not used them either but they are a credible company.

Comment: I'm already scanning 1 HDD with Easeus Data Recovery trial tool, hoping for some good results. With the first solution; would it be possible to do it in Ubuntu or Linux Mint?

Comment: Ive never used it but I dont think Easeus is the correct tool for the job.  Yes, Ubuntu should work fine. I imagine Mint would be OK.  You just need something with XFS support.  You will likely need to install xfs support with a command like 'sudo apt update sudo apt install xfsprogs'

Comment: Will give it a go and later post an update how it went. Thank you very much for your help